# Get the raw event from jQuery

Tags: events, jquery

Is it possible to have access to the original, raw, non-normalized event from the function passed in to bind/live in jQuery? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `originalEvent` property of the [Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object:

```
$(selector).bind("click", function(e) {
    var originalEvent = e.originalEvent;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It's *not* documented... or maybe I can't see.

Comment: @passcod, look in the `Special Properties` section of the linked page.